Extracting a subsequence Cesàro converging to the limsup of the Cesàro sums
Let $X_n$ be a sequence of uniformly bounded random variables — that is, there exists some $K > 0$ such that  $|X_n| \leq K$ almost surely for all $n \in \mathbb N$.
Write $\bar X_N := \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n = 1}^N X_n$, and $Y := \limsup_{N \to \infty} \bar X_N$.
Question: Does there exist some subsequence $X_{n_k}$ such that $\frac{1}{N} \sum_{k=1}^{N} X_{n_k}$ converges to $Y$ almost surely as $N \to \infty$?

No I do not think this is always possible. Take for example a subsequence of $\mathbb{N}$, call it $\{ m_k \}$ and consider the random variables
\begin{equation}
 X_i = \chi_{(0,1/2)},\quad m_k \leq i < m_{k+1}
\end{equation}
if $k$ is even and let $X_i = \chi_{(1/2,1)}$ otherwise. Then if $m_k$ is growing
sufficiently fast we have $Y \equiv 1$ (with your notation). So suppose that for
some subsequence $n_k$ you have that $\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^{N} X_{n_k} =:Z_k $ converges almost everywhere to $1$, by Fatou's lemma you would have
\begin{equation*}
    1 = \int_0^1 \liminf Z_k \leq \liminf_k  \int_0^1 Z_k = \frac{1}{2}.
\end{equation*}

Hm why is $Y = 1$ on $(\frac{1}{2}, 1)$? It seems I get $Y = 1$ on $(0, \frac{1}{2})$ and $0$ otherwise.

Its a bit messy to write down, but the idea is that if  the interval $ [m_k, m_{k+1}) $ is much longer than the interval $[1,m_k)$, when you average the only part of the sequence that counts is in the r.v. having index in the longer interval.

If you need more details I can write down  all the $\epsilon, \delta$ 's

Oh never mind. I misread the construction. What you suggested works. Nice construction!
